Python. Как временно изменить серийный номер физического жесткого диска
Мне нужно временно изменить серийный номер именно физических жестких дисков, которые установлены на компьютере, на заданные. Временно это до перезагрузки, на заданные - это единоразово при запуске скрипта на питоне он меняет серийные номера жестких дисков на те, которые я укажу

В каком формате нужно изменить каждый серийник видно на скрине.
Я пробовал менять через HDD Serial Number Changer, но он меняет только серийные номера логических томов в формате XXXX-XXXX (в 16-тиричной системе исчисления). Также у меня есть спуфер, написанный на питоне, который меняет эти серийные номера ежесекундно, но этот вариант не подходит, т.к. очень легко идентифицируется из-за обилия различных серийников, через которые происходил коннект к аккаунту. Мне нужно слегка модифицированное решение.
Я в программировании совсем новичок, даже азы питона пока не изучил, поэтому меня интересует либо готовое решение либо подсказка, что именно мне гуглить, чтобы самому на питоне решить конкретную узкую задачу в кратчайшие сроки. Буду благодарен за помощь <3
P.S. Извлечь код из спуфера, который есть, я не могу. Он скомпилирован в kdmapper.exe и s.sys, декомпилировать я не умею. Если необходимо, я могу предоставить этот спуфер человеку, который может помочь

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // ТАКЖЕ стоит учитывать, что изменение серийных номеров жестких дисков может иметь юридические и этические ограничения. Рекомендую изучить правовые аспекты этого процесса, чтобы не нарушать законы или правила использования ПО

Читать не умеете? Я НАПИСАЛ ЯСНО: сам не пробовал, что нашёл в сети, то и дал. Что ВЫ предложили? Это финиш, сами ничего не делают, только ходят и высматривают, кто и что.

Я это лично не проверял, это цитата:
Да, программно изменить серийный номер жёсткого диска можно, но это не всегда просто и может потребовать использования специализированного программного обеспечения. Например, можно использовать утилиты вроде AOMEI Partition Assistant Professional или Hard Disk Serial Number Changer. Однако стоит учитывать, что такие изменения могут не поддерживаться всеми операционными системами и файловыми системами.

Ответы от нейросетей тут не котируются, можете удалять

К сожалению софт такого типа меняет только серийник томов. Мне нужен какой-то спуфер, который может работать с физическим диском на 64-битной системе, как я понял. Я нашел на 32-бит только

Clark Devlin: Эти ответы С САЙТОВ, где обсуждаются подобные проблемы: https://qna.habr.com/q/1222430;  https://www.softslot.com/software-2671-hard-disk-serial-number-changer.html; https://www.softslot.com/software-2671-hard-disk-serial-number-changer.html. Что ВЫ лично предложили? НОЛЬ?

user618777, я написал, что я сам этим не занимался, хотя и системщик с большим стажем. За что купил, за то и продаю.

Тут также следует заметить, что изменение серийного номера винта, мягко говоря, не приветствуется в цивилизованном мире. Это вопрос безопасности и возможных расследований со стороны "компетентных органов". Эдак можно и серийный номер баллистической ракеты поменять, а потом дурака валять, мол, "ихтамнебыло". Это всё из этой серии.

Обе упомянутые программы, вопреки названиям и описаниям, меняют идентификаторы файловых систем, а не серийный номер жёсткого диска. Ну а то, что автор уже явно упомянул это в своём вопросе, говорит о том, что вопрос вы даже не читали

Я НАПИСАЛ ЯСНО И ПОНЯТНО: вот есть такая информация, я сам такого не делал, посему не знаю что будет и как!!! Читать не умеете? Что ВЫ предложили?

Я так понимаю, широко не приветствуется именно изменение серийного номера, в моем случае идет речь больше о подмене выдаваемого серийного номера на конкретную сессию до перезагрузки компа. Торжественно клянусь серийники баллистических ракет не менять

Это не моя тема. Честно. Я системщик, но я ищу пути полегче. Что нашёл по теме, то и предлагаю. Найденное не моё, так и написал сразу. Последний раз я сталкивался с такой ситуацией, когда пытались некую прогу привязать к конкретному рабочему месту. Сломали и это в конце концов. В крайнем случае, у всего есть альтернативы. Зачем это надо ещё даже и не знаю. Тема о неприветствовании сейчас более чем актуальна - выясняют чьих ракеты прилетевшие очень даже интенсивно. Посему, если и кропали раньше такое, сейчас вряд ли. Да и привязка винды к оборудованию явно не способствует этим играм.

@FoxFox ну и зачем вы пишете заведомо неверные ответы на вопросы, в которых не компетентны? Вы целенаправленно уничтожаете базу знаний путём разбавления её мусорными отетами? Или вы мазохист, наслаждающийся минусами?)

ЧТО ТАКОЕ? ЧТО НАДО ОТ МЕНЯ? Я уже сказал, пока не будет Вашего решения по теме, Ваше мнение меня НЕ интересует! Я помогаю, если могу! Прочтите наконец ответ!!! Ещё раз, для особо сообразительных: есть такая информация, я не проверял,  берите. Людям не конфетка на лопате нужна только, но и идеи, предложения, попытки, пробы, информация. Это тоже работа!

В чём дело? Какая у Вас задача? Ходить за мной и "критиковать"? Не  надо разбрасываться людьми, способными генерить идеи и пробы. Не надо им мешать! Ещё раз, для очень особо сообразительных: есть информация, спрашивающий, не проверял, неинтересно проверять, берите.  ЭТО НЕ РЕШЕНИЕ! ЭТО ИНФОРМАЦИЯ!

@FoxFox вы не помогаете, вы мусорите бесполезной информацией, которая в данном случае уже написана прямо в тексте вопроса. Генерировать идеи и пробы может любая тупая нейросеть — разумный человек должен уметь выбирать то, что действительно полезно

Я закончил. Мне НЕ интересно.

@FoxFox надеюсь, вам стало не интересно продолжать писать чушь в ответах)

@FoxFox "ЭТО НЕ РЕШЕНИЕ! ЭТО ИНФОРМАЦИЯ!" А зачем тогда это писать в ответ, если это не решение? И пожалуйста отключите CAPS-LOCK.
